# Verify Apache Isn't Processing Proxy Requests

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

We have an apache web server setup in our DMZ that serves most pages, and proxies application requests to a backend server. There is only one place in the config file that has ProxyRequests and it is set to off (ProxyRequests Off).

However, I keep seeing entries like these in our access logs:

```
[11/Feb/2011:05:13:22 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://ocala.craigslist.org/lab/2204935056.html HTTP/1.1 302 240 "http://ocala.craigslist.org/lab/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:13:32 -0500] 92.240.68.152 GET http://phoenix.craigslist.org/wvl/tag/ HTTP/1.1 302 229 "http://phoenix.craigslist.org/wvl/tag/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:13:42 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://indianapolis.craigslist.org/sec/ HTTP/1.1 302 225 "http://indianapolis.craigslist.org/sec/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:13:52 -0500] 92.240.68.152 GET http://washingtondc.craigslist.org/mld/crs/2206881434.html HTTP/1.1 302 244 "http://washingtondc.craigslist.org/mld/crs/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:14:01 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://chicago.craigslist.org/nch/tix/2206985769.html HTTP/1.1 302 244 "http://chicago.craigslist.org/nch/tix/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:14:11 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://boston.craigslist.org/nos/ofc/ HTTP/1.1 302 229 "http://boston.craigslist.org/nos/ofc/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:14:20 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://boston.craigslist.org/nwb/hum/ HTTP/1.1 302 229 "http://boston.craigslist.org/nwb/hum/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:14:28 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://newyork.craigslist.org/brk/sks/ HTTP/1.1 302 229 "http://newyork.craigslist.org/brk/sks/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:14:38 -0500] 92.240.68.152 GET http://newyork.craigslist.org/mnh/reb/2208492687.html HTTP/1.1 302 244 "http://newyork.craigslist.org/mnh/reb/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:14:47 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://lexington.craigslist.org/fbh/ HTTP/1.1 302 225 "http://lexington.craigslist.org/fbh/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:14:57 -0500] 92.240.68.153 GET http://greenville.craigslist.org/pts/ HTTP/1.1 302 225 "http://greenville.craigslist.org/pts/"
[11/Feb/2011:05:15:07 -0500] 92.240.68.152 GET http://denver.craigslist.org/thp/ HTTP/1.1 302 225 "http://denver.craigslist.org/thp/"
```

This concerns me because we usually get these, but I can normally find a correlating entry in the error log stating that the file couldn't be found under the default virtual host.

How could I definitively verify that these proxy requests are truly not being carried out?

Comment: The server is returning 302 HTTP error code (redirect). Is this OK with you?

Comment: I would rather a 403 be returned if it's a proxy request. I don't know if that's normal convention, or if there is some other convention used.